# Optimum is achieved when both variables are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

Consider the problem $\max_{y,z:\|y\|_\infty,\|z\|_\infty \leq 1}y^TBz$, where $B$ is symmetric, positive semidefinite, $y,z\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\|z\|_\infty=\max_{i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}}|z_i|$.

It turns out the max is always achieved when $y=z$ (so we can simplify to the problem $\max_{z:\|z\|_\infty \leq 1}z^TBz$), but I'd like to convince myself this is true.

I am reading through some optimization notes and this claim was made. 
One route I am considering right now is to fix $z$ s.t. $\|z\|_\infty \leq 1$.  But I'm having justifying why $\max_{y:\|y\|_\infty \leq 1}y^TBz=z^TBz$

Comment: The place I'd be inclined to start would be to expand $y,z$ in the eigenvector basis, getting something of the form $y^T B z = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i \lambda_i$. If you were using the Euclidean norm, then we could then force the issue to the boundary (why?), get the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2 = 1$, and then use Lagrange multipliers or something to this effect. But I don't know how to deal with the infinity norm issue.

Comment: @Ian: Notice that the maximum is achieved particularly when $\|y\|_\infty=\|z\|_\infty=1$, just by scaling.

Comment: @AlexR. I fully agree. But that doesn't lead to any convenient constraint in terms of $a_i,b_i$ like it would in the Euclidean setup.

Comment: @user251257 It's true for positive semidefinite matrices.

Comment: @A.G. Yeah, saw your answer. $(y-z)^T B (y-z) \ge 0$ was a nice trick :)

Comment: @user251257 It works for any $p$-norm. Actually, it works for any set $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ if we replace $\|z\|\le 1$ with $z\in K$.

Comment: @A.G. oh true. You should add that to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma:** If $B$ is positive semidefinite then 
$$
\max_{\|y\|_\infty\le 1,\|z\|_\infty\le 1}y^TBz=\max_{\|z\|_\infty\le 1}z^TBz.
$$
*Proof:*

$\fbox{$\le$}$ Since $(y-z)^TB(y-z)\ge 0$ we have for $\|y\|_\infty\le 1$ and $\|z\|_\infty\le 1$
$$
2y^TBz\le y^TBy+z^TBz\le 2\max_{\|z\|_\infty\le 1}z^TBz\quad
\Rightarrow\quad y^TBz\le \max_{\|z\|_\infty\le 1}z^TBz\quad
\Rightarrow\quad 
$$
$$
\max_{\|y\|_\infty\le 1,\|z\|_\infty\le 1}y^TBz\le\max_{\|z\|_\infty\le 1}z^TBz.
$$
$\fbox{$\ge$}$ For $\|z\|_\infty\le 1$ we have
$$
z^TBz\le \max_{\|y\|_\infty\le 1}y^TBz\le 
\max_{\|y\|_\infty\le 1,\|z\|_\infty\le 1}y^TBz\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\max_{\|z\|_\infty\le 1}z^TBz\le\max_{\|y\|_\infty\le 1,\|z\|_\infty\le 1}y^TBz.
$$

---

**P.S.** Actually, exactly the same proof works if we replace the conditions $\|y\|_\infty\le 1$ and $\|z\|_\infty\le 1$ with $y,z\in K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ for any set $K$. So the maximum of a bilinear form being the same as of the corresponding quadratic form is a structural property of positive semidefinite matrices.

Comment: Very nice & thorough, thx!